# How to properly await successful upload with fetch?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, es6-promise, fetch-api

I am currently trying to upload a sizable batch of photos (~150-200) one at a time as Base64 to the Cloudinary API using fetch. This is my painful workaround after Expo (SDK 35) not supporting blobs and Firebase not accepting Base64 images.

In my application, photos are stored inside subdirectories. My desired outcome is to have a function that takes a list of directories and individually uploads each image inside each directory. Currently when I run this function, it appropriately looks inside a directory and returns an array of all files inside the directory. But rather than it calling uploadImage and waiting for completion before attempting the next upload, it attempts to upload every photo at once.

Ideally, the function would upload all photos inside a subdirectory one-by-one before moving to the next. My code is listed below.

```
const hardDirs = [

{
  photoDirectory: "exampleDir1",
},

{
  photoDirectory: "exampleDir2",
},

{
  photoDirectory: "exampleDir3",
},

{
  photoDirectory: "exampleDir4",
},

];

//Parse through directories
async function _directoryNavigator(documentId) { 
  //TODO: SWITCH TO ASYNCSTORAGE KEY FOR DIRECTORIES
  for (let i = 0; i < hardDirs.length; i++) {
    let localDir = FileSystem.documentDirectory + hardDirs[i].photoDirectory;
    //supply both appropriate path format and name of directory to retrieve files and supply new folder name
    let directoryFolder = hardDirs[i].photoDirectory;
    //documentId is auto-generated string supplied by Firebase Cloud Firestore for associated scope JSON schema
    let firebaseDoc = documentId;
    console.log("getting directory " + directoryToUpload);
    await _uploadFromDirectory(localDir, directoryFolder, firebaseDoc);
  }
}

//Return list of each file in directory, create upload
_uploadFromDirectory = async (localDir, directoryFolder, firebaseDoc) => { 
  console.log("enumerate from directory");
  let directoryContents = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(localDir);
  for (let i = 0; i < directoryContents.length; i++) {
    let uri = directoryContents[i];
    console.log("getting image inside directory" + imageFile);
    await createFileUpload(imageFile, localDir, directoryFolder, firebaseDoc);
  }
}

createFileUpload = async (uri, localDir, directoryFolder, firebaseDoc) => {
  console.log("create base64 file for upload");
  let imagePath = `${localDir}/${uri}`;
  //console.log("uploadAsFile", imagePath);
  const response = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(
    imagePath,
    {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
    });

  let base64Img = `data:image/jpg;base64,${response}`;
  let apiUrl = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/USERNAME/image/upload';
  let data = {
    "file": base64Img,
    "upload_preset": "PRESET",
    "folder": `${directoryFolder}`,
    "public_id": `${firebaseDoc}/${directoryFolder}/${uuid.v4()}`
  };

  const upload = await uploadImage(apiUrl, data);
}

async function uploadImage(apiUrl, data) {
  try {
    console.log("upload image")
    let response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'POST',
    });
    let data = await response.json();
    return data.secure_url;
    console.log(data.secure_url);
  } catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
}
```

I am still relatively new to React Native and trying to understand ES6 as best as possible. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like it would be uploading things one at a time to me; you don't have `Promise.all` or anything like that. How do you know it's trying to upload them all at once?

Comment: I've read that console.log can be somewhat of a false flag when it comes to tracking the execution of functions with await... but my terminal output with the above logs gives me a ton of this: `upload image
getting image inside directory1572387353651.jpg
create base64 file for upload
upload image
getting image inside directory1572548413671.jpg
create base64 file for upload
upload image
` I would interpret this as uploadImage being called each time regardless of the asset URL not being returned from the previous upload?

Comment: Oh, ha, I see what you mean. It's just because you're doing a `return data.secure_url;` before the `console.log(data.secure_url)`, so if you're expecting that console log, it'll never happen since the return statement will bypass the following statements. I think it's doing what you expect, your logging was just a bit incorrect.

Comment: @Jacob Accidental concurrency would more likely be caused by a forgotten `await`, not by an explicit `Promise.all`, but I agree that the code seems to be working as is.

Comment: @thisismyclevername may i ask , why did you write `await response.json();` instead of `response.json()` ?. Isn't `response` already resolved from `await fetch(...` ??